# The Name of the Tool from the Picture

Tags: entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019

Goal:
The name of the tool in order review the code as a sql code when you apply the input linq code C#

(https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/imported/2325-1-2fbc0f9f-774f-441e-a91c-acdd4a812ba7.png)

Problem:
What is the name of the tool? Can you find it at Visual studio 2019 or do you need an additional tool that need to be downloaded?

Info:
The picture is from this page (https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-tools/entity-framework-performance-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/)

Thank you!

Comment: My guess would be Red-Gate's ANTS performance profiler. A similar tool would be Hibernating Rhino's Entity Framework Profiler.

Comment: https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Comment: The blog literally says: "If we look in ANTS at what happens when this code runs, we see a query run once to get a list of schools in New York, but another query is also run 500 times to fetch Pupil information."

Comment: But you should know that "what's this tool" is an off-topic question on Stack Overflow.